# Set default browser

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an application for a web browser. Just like other browsers(Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, etc.), I need to ask the user to set my application as the default browser.

Is there a way we can set default browser through code?

Answer (score 5):

According to this answer on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/0dec1d9d-f6bb-4c4c-926b-83acd2da985c/how-to-set-default-browser-in-windows-8-using-c) you need to change a registry key:

```
RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\shell\\Associations\\UrlAssociations\\http\\UserChoice", true);
string browser = regkey.GetValue("Progid").ToString();

if (browser != "IE.HTTP")
{
    regkey.SetValue("Progid", "IE.HTTP");
}
```

This sets the `Progid` to that from Internet Explorer. You should create an own and register your `Progid` here.

Also see this full explaining [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: As I understand, "IE.HTTP" is used for Internet explorer. What will be used in it's place for my application? 
How do I create Progid for my application?

Comment: @STT: Added a link to the answer which answers all questions.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to this. Could you please help me on how can I create my own Progid using C# code?

Comment: It's just nothing more than creating a registry key. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx) and use the keys described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#reg_examples).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I successfully created the ProgId. However, when I set my browser as default using the above code(replacing ProgId), my html/htm files are still being opened by the previous default browser only. Is there anything I'm still missing?

Comment: Did you follow the entire example in the link provided?

Comment: Yes I did. I am also able to see my application in the default programs list. But when I set my application as default through the above code using the ProgId I created, all the .htm/.html files are still being opened by my previous default browser.
1 doubt: Here we are setting HTTP Url association to our apps ProgId. Is there any way we can set the default for .htm/.html extension too?

Comment: I even tried to set IE as default browser but all in vain

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have nothing to reproduce this with and I can only rely on the documentation provided my Microsoft. I would love to help you, but not sure how.